# Condition for maximal filter of a lattice to be completely prime

Tags: general-topology, locales, frame-theory

*Background definitions.*

- A **frame** $(\mathbb X,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set with arbitrary joins (least upper bounds) and finite meets (greatest lower bounds).
- A **filter** $F\subseteq \mathbb X$ is a nonempty up-closed proper subset of $X$ that is closed under finite meets.
- A filter is **maximal** when it is not contained in any strictly greater filter.
- A filter $F\subseteq\mathbb X$ is **completely prime** when for every $X\subseteq\mathbb X$, if $\bigvee X\in F$ then $x\in F$ for some $x\in X$.

Call a completely prime filter a **point**.

*A motivating observation.*

It is not in general the case that a maximal filter is necessarily completely prime.  For a counterexample, consider $\mathbb Q$ (the rationals) with their usual topology and take the frame of its open sets.  This has a filter $F_\pi$, which is the set of open neighbourhoods of $\pi$ (for $\mathbb Q$ embedded in $\mathbb R$).  This is not completely prime because $(,\pi) \cup (\pi,)=\mathbb Q$ is in $F_\pi$ but neither $(,\pi)$ nor $(\pi,)$ is.

*Questions.*

1. What is the name for the property of a frame, that every maximal filter be completely prime?
2. What property does this correspond to on point-set topologies?

*A remark.*

I can see that such a condition seems to have to do with being compact -- the condition says using the terminology above that every maximal filter yields a point, after all! -- but I can't quite put my finger on a precise connection.  In particular, Wikipedia has a list [characterisations of compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), but the filters referred to there are in a full powerset, not in a frame open sets.  So I'm missing some piece of information.  I hope someone can advise.

Thank you.

Comment: I corrected a typo in your post: filters are closed under finite meets, not joins. Also, I added "completely" in two places (including the title), since "prime" is a weaker notion than "completely prime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few comments/corrections:

- In your definition of frame, you left out the condition that finite meets distribute over arbitrary joins.
- In any distributive lattice, every maximal filter $F$ is prime, i.e., if $a\vee b \in F$, then $a\in F$ or $b\in F$. Note that in your example, the filter $F_\pi$ is not just not completely prime, it's not even prime. So it can't be maximal as you claim.
- To see this explicitly, consider, for example, the filter generated by $F_\pi \cup \{(-\infty,\pi)\}$. This is a filter properly containing $F_\pi$: it consists of all open sets which contain an interval of the form $(a,\pi)$ for some $a<\pi$.
- It's not going to be easy to give an explicit description of a maximal filter in the frame of open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, none of the completely prime filters corresponding to points in $\mathbb{Q}$ are maximal.

Ok, now let's consider your actual question. Let $X$ be a spatial frame, and let $S$ be its corresponding topological space of points (so $X$ is isomorphic to the frame of open sets in $S$). Note that $S$ is a [sober space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space). I haven't thought carefully about the situation for non-spatial frames or non-sober spaces. For $U\in X$, write $[U]$ for the corresponding open set in $S$.

Suppose $F$ is a filter in $X$ which is simultaneously completely prime and maximal. Since $F$ is completely prime, it corresponds to a point $p\in S$. Since $F$ is maximal, for every $U\in X$ such that $U\notin F$, there exists $V\in F$ such that $U\wedge V = \bot$. Translating to topological language, for every open set $[U]$ with $p\notin [U]$, there is an open neighborhood $p\in [V]$ such that $[U]$ and $[V]$ are disjoint. Equivalently, the closure of $p$ has nonempty interior, i.e., $p$ is somewhere dense. Note that if $S$ is $T_1$ (every point is closed), then $p$ is somewhere dense if and only if $p$ is an isolated point.

You ask about frames with the property that *every* maximal filter is completely prime. I don't know if this property has a name, but I can prove that the following are equivalent:

1. Every maximal filter in $X$ is completely prime.
2. Every cover of $S$ by *closed* sets has a finite subcover.
3. $S$ is a finite union of [irreducible closed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_component).

For the equivalence of 1 and 2, note that a filter in $X$ corresponds to a family of open sets in $S$ with the finite intersection property: any finite intersection of sets in the family is non-empty. Assuming 1, since every filter extends to a maximal filter, every family of open sets in $S$ with the finite intersection property contains a point. Conversely, if every family of open sets in $S$ with the finite intersection property contains a point, then every maximal filter $M$ extends to a completely prime filter, which must be equal to $M$ by maximality.

Thus 1 is equivalent to the condition that any family of open sets in $S$ with the finite intersection property has non-empty intersection. Taking complements and the contrapositive, we get 2.

For the equivalence of 2 and 3, note that we can cover $S$ by closed sets $\{\mathrm{cl}(\{p\})\mid p\in S\}$. Assuming $2$, this cover has a finite subcover, so there are finitely many points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ such that $S = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathrm{cl}(\{p_i\})$, and each set $\mathrm{cl}(\{p_i\})$ is closed and irreducible. Conversely, suppose $S = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$, where each $C_i$ is closed and irreducible. Since $S$ is the space of points of a frame, it is a sober space, so each $C_i$ is the closure of a single point $p_i$. Now suppose $S = \bigcup_{j\in J} V_j$ is a cover of $S$ by closed sets. For each $1\leq i \leq n$, there is some $j_i\in J$ such that $p_i\in V_{j_i}$. Then $C_i\subseteq V_{j_i}$, so $S = \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{j_i}$.

Note that if $S$ is $T_1$, then it has a cover $S = \bigcup_{p\in S} \{p\}$ by irreducible closed sets, so under the equivalent conditions above, $S$ is a finite discrete space.

Comment: Thank you for this reply.  Are you able to expand on the step marked with [Here] below?
*"Translating to topological language, for every open set [] with ∉[], there is an open neighborhood ∈[] such that [] and [] are disjoint. [Here] Equivalently, the closure of  has nonempty interior"*
The equivalence is not clear to me.  Consider for example 0 in the real numbers with its usual topology.  Then for every U with 0 not in U, there exists an open neighbourhood V of 0 such that U and V are disjoint.  However, the closure of 0 is {0} and the open interior is empty.

Thank you.

Comment: @Jim Your example doesn't work: $(0,1)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ which does not contain $0$ and is not disjoint from any open neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Jim Here's a proof of the equivalence: Suppose that for every open set $U$ with $p\notin U$, there is an open neighborhood $p\in V$ such that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Let $U$ be the complement of the closure of $\{p\}$. Then $U$ is open and $p\notin U$. So there is an open neighborhood $p\in V$ such that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Since $p\in V$, $V$ is nonempty, and since $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, $V$ is contained in the closure of $\{p\}$. Thus the closure of $\{p\}$ has non-empty interior.

Comment: Conversely, suppose the closure of $\{p\}$ has non-empty interior. Let $C$ be the closure of $\{p\}$, and let $V$ be the interior of $C$. I claim that $p\in V$. If not, then $C\setminus V$ is a closed set containing $p$, so $C\subseteq C\setminus V$, contradicting the fact that $V$ is a non-empty subset of $C$. Now let $U$ be an open set with $p\notin U$. The complement of $U$ is a closed set containing $p$, so it contains $C$. Thus $C$ is disjoint from $U$, and hence $V$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ which is disjoint from $U$, as desired.

Comment: Of course.  Thank you, this is very clear.